# Linear Search on Array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to create a program that takes a user input (a number) and then the program should have that number and apply a search to the array and output the corresponding title by matching the index and the number the user inputted. However during run time, nothing happens. I have set breakers in my code and noticed a problem with the for loop (search algorithm). Please help me and let me know what is wrong is my search algorithm.

Edit: Found out what the error was. Typo in my array assignments.

```
    private void btnFindActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:  

    // declares an array 
   String[] listOfBooks = new String [101];

   // assigns index in array to book title 
   listOfBooks[1] = "The Adventures of Tom Sawyer"; 
   listOfBooks[2] = "Huckleberry Finn"; 
   listOfBooks[3] = "The Sword in the Stone";
   listOfBooks[4] = "Stuart Little";
   listOfBooks[5] = "Treasure Island";
   listOfBooks[6] = "Test";
   listOfBooks[7] = "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland";
   listOfBooks[8] = "Twenty Thousand Leagues Under the Sea";
   listOfBooks[9] = "Peter Pan";
   listOfBooks[10] = "Charlotte's Web";
   listOfBooks[11] = "A Little Princess";
   listOfBooks[12] = "Little Women";
   listOfBooks[13] = "Black Beauty";
   listOfBooks[14] = "The Merry Adventures of Robin Hood";
   listOfBooks[15] = "Robinson Crusoe";
   listOfBooks[16] = "Anne of Green Gables";
   listOfBooks[17] = "Little House in the Big Woods";
   listOfBooks[18] = "Swiss Family Robinson";
   listOfBooks[19] = "The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe";
   listOfBooks[20] = "Heidi";
   listOfBooks[21] = "A Winkle in Time";
   listOfBooks[222] = "Mary Poppins";

    // gets user input 
    String numberInput = txtNumberInput.getText();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(numberInput);

    // Linear search to match index number  and user input number
        for(int i = 0; i < listOfBooks.length; i++) {
        if(numberInput.equals(listOfBooks[i]))
        {
        txtLinearOutput.setText(listOfBooks[i]);
        break; 
        }
```

Comment: tell me clearly you retrive element from the index Am i reight

Comment: What is the run time error and which line of your program throws the exception?

Comment: Tell me what run time error you have

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing an array java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44292770/accessing-an-array-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at working with [Java Arrays](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_arrays.htm). You are going out of bounds of the array's index. You created an array of size 22 but are trying to access index 100.

> You can create an array by using the new operator with the following
>   syntax:
>
> `arrayRefVar = new String[arraySize];` The above statement does two
>   things:
>
> It creates an array using new String[arraySize];
>
> It assigns the reference of the newly created array to the variable
>   arrayRefVar.
>
> Declaring an array variable, creating an array, and assigning the
>   reference of the array to the variable can be combined in one
>   statement, as shown below:
>
> `String[] arrayRefVar = new String[arraySize];`

This creates an array of size `arraySize` and it is indexed starting from **0  to arraySize-1**

Comment: Would it be better to use an ArrayList?

Comment: Yes, you could use an ArrayList. For this simple case an array is fine as long as you respect the indexing and its size.

Comment: I changed it to [100] and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: No, change the array's size to 101 or the last index to 99.

Comment: Oh ok I changed it to 101, and the errors went away but now when I click the find button, nothing is happening. Is there a problem with my loop?

Comment: You changed it to 101, but please go through java array's. That is a basic concept you need to grasp first.

Comment: @Sid, I apologize, but I am a beginner.

Comment: I assume you are using an IDE, if so please put some breakpoints in your code and check what values your variables contain. This is another essential skill and will likely result in you finding out why nothing happens.
If you still have more problems please post a new question with concise code and error.

Comment: When you set to `numberInput`, you *are* setting the book name, right? Not its index?

Comment: numberInput is what number the user inputs. Then that number is supposed to be used in the for loop to find the corresponding index.

Comment: @Sid I have set breakers and noticed something wrong with my for loop. Array has correct values stored in the index.

Comment: @MitPatel as I ILikeTau has correctly noticed.. if your `numberInput` is set to 10 and you check `numberInput.equals(listOfBooks[i])` then you are checking if string 10 equals "Name of movie" .. which will never be equal.

Comment: How would I represent it so that the input number would equal an index?

Comment: @MitPatel please join [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/87333/debugging-linear-search?tab=general) this is becoming to broad to answer here.

Comment: I do not have enough rep to talk in chat.

Comment: I suggest checking more on java arrays and loops. Once you have done the necessary research please post another question with relevant code and any errors you encounter. A well researched post which demonstrates effort will be answered by the community and will also earn you the reputation you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `listOfBooks` has a size of 22, but you're trying to add "Peter Pan" at index 24, which causes the exception (and so will everything else after it).

Also, why are you not setting the books in order? The 22 would only work if you set them to consecutive indices, not in the random skipping you have.