# Accessing an array java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, null

```
for(int i=0;i<dictionary.words.length;i++){
    if(dictionary.words[i].length() <=maxWordlength){
        count++;
        smallWordDictionary[i]=dictionary.words[i]; 
    }
}
```

I used this code to store the strings from a dictionary array into an array containing strings with a shorter word length. I now want to pass this array alongside a random number to the following method(*to create a randomly generated word*):

```
randomWord(smallWordDictionary, outcome);
```

When I use the following method:

```
static void randomWord(String [] array, int number){
     System.out.println(array[number]);
}
```

The console prints out `null` and I'm not sure why. How can I get the console to print out a string that corresponds to its element within the `smallWordDictionary` array?

Comment: The console is not smart, if it is printing null it's because that element in the array contains a null value. We need the full code to understand your logic.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and improve your question.

Comment: I agree with @GhostCat, we need enough code here in order to reproduce this and see the full picture. It's hard to see where the pipe is leaking if you can only see the top of the drain and can't open the cabinet doors.

Answer (score 2):

You're not storing anything in `smallWordDictionary[i]` when the length is more than `maxWordlength`.

The default value for your array members is `null`, not empty string. (The default value for any array members of reference type is `null`.)

Consequently, some of your random indices will point to an array member that is still null.

Solutions include:

- Build a smaller array, that includes only the words that passed. No nulls will be present.
- Place empty string in each member that does not pass.
- Check for null when printing.

**Build a smaller array**

The easiest way to do this is with a List.

```
List<String> smallWordList = new ArrayList<>;

for(int i=0;i<dictionary.words.length;i++){
    if(dictionary.words[i].length() <=maxWordlength){
        count++;
        smallWordList.add( dictionary.words[i] ); 
    }
}

smallWordDictionary = smallWordList.toArray( new String[] );
```

Note that `count` is the sames as `smallerWords.size()` or `smallerWordDictionary.length`.

**Place empty string in each member that does not pass**

```
for(int i=0;i<dictionary.words.length;i++){
    if(dictionary.words[i].length() <=maxWordlength){
        count++;
        smallWordDictionary[i]=dictionary.words[i]; 
    }
    else {
        smallWordDictionary[i]=""; 
    }
}
```

**Check for null when printing**

```
static void randomWord(String [] array, int number){
    String member = array[number];
    System.out.println( (null == member) ? "" : member);
}
```

Comment: I intended it to be that way, because I only want words of 6 characters or less.

Comment: You asked why you're seeing "null" printed out. This is why. Let me add some code that will illustrate how to avoid it.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I understand what you are saying now, so how do i avoid this?

Comment: I tried the empty string method and it stopped 'null' being printed out, however my method wont print any strings out at all

Comment: Sounds like either your random choice is always hitting an index without a value, or you're somehow not filling any array members with a value. I strongly recommend building a smaller array (option 1 above). As far as I can tell, you don't need the indices in `smallWordDictionary` to correspond to indices in `dictionary`, and you don't need null values at all.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but I've been told not to use lists during this task. Is there a way of building a smaller array without a list

Comment: Yes, at least two ways. You could initialize `smallWordDictionary` to the same size as `dictionary`, but fill just a prefix of it, and keep track of the length. This results in wasted *memory*. Another option is to traverse the dictionary twice, first to find the count, so that you can create an array of the correct size, then traverse it again to fill the smaller array. This results in an up-front additional linear traversal, but doesn't cost anything extra after initialization. Another option is to mix these two, resulting in only one traversal of the larger array.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example of the second option please

Comment: It will include two `for` loops whose control expressions and first statement look exactly like what you have. One of these will count the members that pass. Then you'd create the smaller array using the count. Then you'd have the second `for` that fills the smaller array, using a different index than `i`. Given that this is homework, this is code that you should write yourself.